# Elasticsearch: How to rank edge-nGrams higher than othe nGrams?

Tags: elasticsearch, n-gram

I have some data like this:

```
**Places**
1  Eunos
2  Sun Rosier
```

I have specified a nGram analyzer like this:

```
{

 "places": {


         "properties": {


             "place":{
                 "type" : "string",
                 "index_analyzer": "nGram_analyzer"
}
}
}
```

When I query to match a partial word like 'eun', i get both the places (Eunos and Sun rosier ) back. (I have turned  fuziness on in the query to account for spelling mistakes). But the 'Sun rosier' result is displayed higher than 'Eunos' result. How can I ensure that edge nGrams are ranked higher than other nGrams? Any help will be appreciated :) Thanks